# Polygon hole is sometime not empty (Google Maps Api)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps-api

I am using google map api to draw a polygon and 4 holes inside of it, three holes are working fine but the fourth one is rendering like shaded polygon
Below is the defined code i am using to create polygon

```
 const paths = [_coordinates];
    const holes = JSON.parse(coordinate_holes);
    console.log("here is the coordinates",isClockwise(JSON.parse(zone_coordinates)));
    holes.map(hole => {
        paths.push(shortLatLng(hole).reverse())
    });
```

Passing path to JSX

```
  if(shape==="polygon") { 
      return (
        <div key={id}>
          <Polygon
            paths={paths} 
            options={getOptions(shape)}>
        </Polygon>
        {infoBox(zone)}
        </div>
    )};
```

Not Working holes

```
[
    {
      "latitude":39.7398066162147785007618949748575687408447265625,
      "longitude":-104.9892461299896098125827847979962825775146484375
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.73941061515532879866441362537443637847900390625,
      "longitude":-104.989743344485759735107421875
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.73950136559911783251664019189774990081787109375,
      "longitude":-104.98886726796627044677734375
    }
  ],
```

Working Holes

```
[
  [
    {
      "latitude":39.74007319377148661487808567471802234649658203125,
      "longitude":-104.99013327062129974365234375
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.74009794366639880536240525543689727783203125,
      "longitude":-104.9895716831087923992527066729962825775146484375
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.7396276941428965301383868791162967681884765625,
      "longitude":-104.989925734698772430419921875
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "latitude":39.7399659441241084323337418027222156524658203125,
      "longitude":-104.9889316409826136577976285479962825775146484375
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.74006236568965277911047451198101043701171875,
      "longitude":-104.98836301267147064208984375
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.73964703012405408344420720823109149932861328125,
      "longitude":-104.988613128662109375
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "latitude":39.7396194441226242588527384214103221893310546875,
      "longitude":-104.98831272125244140625
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.740045865752193776643252931535243988037109375,
      "longitude":-104.9878191947937153827297152020037174224853515625
    },
    {
      "latitude":39.739454443509572456605383194983005523681640625,
      "longitude":-104.9878228828311108600246370770037174224853515625
    }
  ]
]
```

problem is only happening in some of the cases and I am unable to figure out what is the reason behind it, I already checked that the outer region is clock-wise and the inner holes are anticlockwise
please help if you can thanks

Comment: Please include data structure for working holes and non-working hole.

Comment: I have added. Please check